# iOS iTunes Filesharing Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, itunes

I have an app for iOS that uses Filesharing to provide the user with a couple of downloaded files. This works great, but there are a couple of files that I don't want the user to have access to.

Can I provide a custom folder where iTunes can get the data from or what can I do to prevent these files from being accessed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the files you want to exclude from filesharing either in (a subfolder in) **Library** or **Caches** Folder. Library will be backuped with iTunes, Caches not.

Answer (score 3):

From [Sharing Files with the User](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW10) section from docs:

> **Important:** In iTunes, users can
>   manipulate only the top-level items in
>   the Documents directory. Users cannot
>   see the contents of subdirectories but
>   can delete those directories or copy
>   their contents to the desktop. Take
>   this into consideration when deciding
>   where to put files in this directory.

So with File sharing enabled you cannot hide files in Documents folder - you rather should put it in another folder in application sandbox:

> If you do not want files to be shared
>   with the user, put them in your
>   application’s Library directory. If
>   none of the standard Library
>   subdirectories are appropriate, create
>   a private directory inside the Library
>   directory and give it the name of your
>   application’s bundle ID. You can then
>   use that directory to store any files
>   that are private to your application.